# "logical operator" behaves unexpectedly in python

Tags: python-3.x

Why does the following behave unexpectedly in Python?

print('a' > 'b')

> > > False

print('a' > 'A')

> > > True

Comment: Do you mean comparison operators?

Comment: You need to learn about ASCII values from [here](https://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html)

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Yes!

Comment: @PiNaKa30 Got it!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `>`, `<`, `>=`, or `<=` on strings, they get compared by their ASCII value. The ASCII value of `'a'` is 97, `'b'` is 98, and `'A'` is 65. So `A` is lower than `a`, because it's earlier in the ASCII table.